# AnimationTimer - showAndWait is not allowed during animation processing

Tags: java, animation, exception, javafx

I'm trying to display an alert dialog box when the player wins the game that I created. However, I get an exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: showAndWait is not allowed during animation or layout processing
```

I tried adding `stop()` in the `AnimationTimer` but it didn't work, still threw the same exception:

```
if (ball.getBall().getCenterY() == 0) {
                //computer lost!
                stop();

                Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
                alert.setTitle(null);
                alert.setHeaderText(null);
                alert.setContentText("Good game. You won! Click OK to exit.");

                alert.showAndWait(); //exception thrown here
                System.exit(0);
            }
```

Comment: The exception is exactly as described: you can't call `showAndWait()` from an animation. This isn't explicitly mentioned in the `Alert` documentation, but it is in the documentation for [`Stage` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#showAndWait--).

Comment: @James_D Ok. Is there a workaround? How do I stop the timer and then tell the player they won?

Comment: I added an answer with a workaround that should work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can only call `showAndWait()` in an event handler, not from within an animation. This is not explicitly documented in the `Alert` class, though it is documented in the [documentation for `Stage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#showAndWait--).

Call `show()` instead, and use a handler for the `onHidden` event for the alert to invoke something when the alert is closed:

```
if (ball.getBall().getCenterY() == 0) {
    //computer lost!

    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
    alert.setTitle(null);
    alert.setHeaderText(null);
    alert.setContentText("Good game. You won! Click OK to exit.");

    alert.setOnHidden(evt -> Platform.exit());

    alert.show(); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly. Could you explain what `evt -> Platform.exit()` means?

Comment: @Stardust I'm not sure what you mean. It's just the handler for the event. [`Platform.exit()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#exit--) is the method to exit JavaFX, this just means this is executed when the `hidden` event happens on the alert (i.e. the alert is closed).

Comment: oh, it's just that I haven't seen that notation (with the `->`)

Comment: It's a lambda expression. They were introduced in Java 8, a little more than three years ago...

Comment: @Stardust But you're using JavaFX. How are you writing event handlers if you're not using lambdas? Surely you're not creating anonymous inner classes for all your event handlers?

Comment: I normally let my IDE autocomplete my statements, will use lambdas from now on as they seem a lot more simpler and easier to understand

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to put your code into a private method and call using a method reference or lambda runnable in a Platform.runLater() call.

```
Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
alert.setTitle(null);
alert.setHeaderText(null);
alert.setContentText("Good game. You won! Click OK to exit.");

alert.showAndWait(); //exception thrown here
System.exit(0);
```

This make the dialog pop up outside of a timer cycle and should fix the problem.